# jquery working okay on local server but doesn't work properly on the live server. all ajax jquery requests hangs a lot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My jquery code works okay on my local machine including the ajax requests.

But after I uploaded the website, the jquery doesn't work properly as the request "hang" or take a long time to process or do not process at all.

My website is [smartminds.co.ke][1] .

I can pass the login credentials so that someone can login and see what I am talking about.

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console

Comment: I think you need to call JS files based on the need. Like fancybox is not needed on home page then you can skip that. and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any errors.

Comment: The only errors are on some css files.  Two of them which return a 404 on the console.